# How to add <title> to Custom Pages in WP's function.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress theme that creates custom pages.

However, when SEO Yoast is used to make custom title and meta descriptions, all the custom pages have the same title tags as index.php (the homepage). This is a red flag for google webmaster tools obviously.

```
add_action('theme_query', 'theme_page_query');
function theme_page_query() {
    global $wp_query;

    $act = get_query_var( 'act' );
    if ($act == 'new-wallpapers') {
        query_posts('orderby=post_date&order=DESC&paged='.get_query_var('page'));
    } elseif ($act == 'popular-wallpapers') {
        query_posts('meta_key=theme_hit_download&orderby=meta_value_num post_date&order=DESC&paged='.get_query_var('page'));
    } elseif ($act == 'random-wallpapers') {
        query_posts('orderby=rand&paged='.get_query_var('page'));
    } elseif ($act == 'recent-downloads') {
        query_posts('meta_key=theme_hit_download_time&orderby=meta_value&order=DESC&paged='.get_query_var('page'));
    }
}

   function theme_page_title($title) {
    if (in_array(get_query_var( 'act' ), array(
        'new-wallpapers',
        'popular-wallpapers',
        'random-wallpapers',        
        'recent-downloads',
        ))) {
        $title = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', get_query_var( 'act' )));
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'theme_wp_title', 10, 2 );
function theme_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page, $wp_query;

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    if (in_array(get_query_var( 'act' ), array(
        'new-wallpapers',
        'popular-wallpapers',
        'random-wallpapers',
        'recent-downloads',
        ))) {
        $title = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', get_query_var( 'act' ))) . " {$sep} ";
    }

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) {
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'theme' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }

    return $title;
}
```

I have tried searching, but I cannot find a step-by-step guide and I am not good in PHP. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three steps by

1.`Add a new input box to the admin pages for creating and editing new Posts/Pages`

2.`Save the the value of that input box when that Post/Page is saved`

3.`Echo out a new title as part of the wp_head() function`

[here](http://digwp.com/2010/04/custom-page-titles/) is the detailed explanation..Hope it helps ..Thanks